# How to remove extra spaces at the end of the TextView?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to remove the extra spaces at the end of the text in "TextView", but to no avail. Here is my code.

```
private void userInfo() {
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(profileid);
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (getContext() == null){
                return;
            }

            User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);
            
            username.setText(user.getUsername()); ...
```

THIS IS MINE "MYTEXTㅤㅤ"ㅤ
I WANT TO GET THIS: "MYTEXT"

Comment: Excuse me, I just translated for you!

Comment: I'm really not clear where exactly you are getting spaces from , layout or from database. If you are getting from database use trim() function to remove trailing spaces , or if you have set fixed width in layout change it to wrap content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use trim() function to remove extra space in end of your text

```
user.getUsername().trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

If `user.getUsername()` returns a String, try this:

```
user.getUsername().trim()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use trim() on textview Text. It will trim spaces from beginning and end of the String.

**Use this :**

```
String textviewText = ((String) tv.getText()).trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you should `trim()` the text when you collect the user input (not just name):

```
editText.getText().toString().trim()
```